# How to make a call for 10 digit number in FreeSwitch?

Tags: freeswitch

FreeSwitch has 20 sample phone number between 1000-1019. It is okay to make a call with these numbers.

I've put 5168880000 number in directory folder. It is okay to call 1000 phone number from 5168880000 phone number. However, calling from 5168880000 to 1000 number has failed. All of variation for 5168880000 directory is same as 1000 number.

I believe that I need to change dialplan config file.. Is there way to make a call for 10 digit number? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default FreeSWITCH configuration ("vanilla"), `dialplan/default.xml` contains `<extension name="Local_Extension">` which matches 4-digit numbers starting with 10. That's why your 516... numbers do not match.

I would advise to start with the minimal configuration (https://github.com/xlab1/freeswitch_conf_minimal) and build your dialplan as required. The default configuration has too much stuff which needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Jake, you really need to read the freeswitch book. It will take you a couple of days and will answer most of your questions.

Comment: Yeah, I read the book. found out that it has dial expression set.

Answer (score 1):

2 simple options come to mind:

- add the configuration to an existing configuration
  for instance, find "Local_Extension" in the default dialplan, and change the condition to:

> ```
> <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(10[01][0-9]**|\d{10}**)$">
> ```

- add another configuration
  in the default configuration, add the following

> ```
> <extension name="10digits"> 
>   <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d{10})$">
>     <action application="set" data="dialed_extension=$1"/>
>     <action application="bridge" data="user/${dialed_extension}@${domain_name}"/>
>   </condition>
> </extension>
> ```